# homeomorphism between a circle with a hole and an open interval

Tags: general-topology

I was studying using topology without tears, and end up crying out loud...

The question was Let $X$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$; $X = \{\langle x,y\rangle  : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ and has the subspace topology.

(i) show that $X\backslash \{\langle 1,0 \rangle\}$ is homeomorphic to the open interval $(0,1)$

Little hint would be really appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Do you have enough geometric intuition to find this result believable?

Comment: Hint: Stereographic projection.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I was going to suggest that too, but then the OP would have to take the extra step of showing that $\mathbb{R} \cong (0,1)$ . I feel that the homeomorphism hinted at in the answers are simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the circle with a point missing as an elastic band that has just snapped. Now imagine straightening out the broken band. This should help you see which points on the circle need to go to which points on the interval.

Answer (score 2):

@Justpassingby's answer is a good hint for the intuition.

More rigorously, write the broken unit circle $X \setminus (1,0)$ in polar coordinates $X = \{(1,\theta) \mid \theta \in (0, 2\pi) \}$ and try constructing a homeomorphism following that intuition.